# What are the exact terms of the recent Israeli-Palestinian cease fire?

Tags: israel, palestine, hamas, jerusalem

Israel and the Hamas government of Gaza (or perhaps the Hamas movement?) have recently agreed to a [cease fire](https://apnews.com/article/israel-palestinian-cease-fire-hamas-caac81bc36fe9be67ac2f7c27000c74b). But - what are the exact terms? Is there a text of that available somewhere?

Specifically, Israel has continued violent "policing" action on the temple mount - part of what started the round of violence. Is that allowed by the terms of the cease fire? What about evictions from the Sheikh Jarrah neighborhood?

PS - This question is not about whether any side "won", nor whether the cease-fire was a good idea, nor what would be the long-term implications etc.

Comment: Please note, the "PS" was added after my answer was posted.

Comment: Apparently both the evictions and the municipal police presence at al Aqsa were just flimsy pretexts for Hamas to start violence, since no mention was made of them in the ceasefire. This supports the theory that Hamas was firing rockets only to win brownie points from the Palestinian electorate in the next election, which Abbas may or may not allow before his centennial.

Comment: @ZevSpitz: "Apparently etc." <- No. Also, Hamas did not "start violence". At any rate, where is the text of the cease-fire agreement, which you're referring to?

Comment: @einpoklum [Arabs: Hamas Does Not Care About Palestinian Suffering](https://www.gatestoneinstitute.org/17390/hamas-palestinians-suffering).

Comment: @ZevSpitz: Wow, Saudi royalists, very convincing.

Comment: Well, if you really want to go there, the count by country of the voices in the article are as follows: Saudis 3, UAE 1, Egypt 1, Jordan 1, Bahrain 1, Israeli Arab 1 (the author). Are you honestly expecting an admission by Hamas -- a regime without a free press -- that this was a PR war and nothing else?

Answer (score -5):

As per all news outlets I've checked, the current ceasefire was without any concessions of Israel whatsoever. It is "Silence in exchange for Silence".

An outstanding victory for Israel, who were able to compel Hamas to discontinue the rocket firing without earning any of its goals.

If your findings are different, please write in comments.

Comment: Ah, but what constitutes "silence"? That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @einpoklum, the halt of Israeli airstrikes on Gaza.

Comment: Was that stated explicitly anywhere?

Comment: @einpoklum, sorry but it's not in english; https://www.jdn.co.il/news/1532235/ https://chabad.info/news/676708/

Comment: That link suggests that there there is unclarity regarding what the cease-fire means. Israel states that it means X, there are reports that it means Y. But where is the agreed-upon text? It seems we don't have it.

Comment: @einpoklum, if you don't have the text, and some "sources" are contradicting the official statement of the Israeli cabinet. Then check the facts on the ground, some of which you have stated in your question.